# Why is this error coming up when I try to get double to 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I am creating a simple program to calculate the cost of running a car. The program works just fine but I wanted to see if I could get the final answer to 2 decimal places. I tried using the `'%8.2f'` thing but it said that `no method could be found for println(string, double)`

This is my code:

```
/* Program to calculate the running cost of car */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunningCosts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int TOTAL_DISTANCE = 100000;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the car cost: ");
        double carCost = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the service cost: ");
        double serviceCost = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the service interval: ");
        double serviceInterval = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter km per litre: ");
        double kmPerLitre = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the fuel cost per litre: ");
        double fuelCostPerLitre = in.nextDouble();


        double serviceTotal = (TOTAL_DISTANCE/serviceInterval) * serviceCost;
        System.out.println( "Service Total: " + serviceTotal); //Here

        double fuelCost = (TOTAL_DISTANCE/kmPerLitre) * fuelCostPerLitre;
        System.out.println( "Fuel Cost: " + fuelCost); //Here

        double totalCost = carCost + fuelCost + serviceTotal;

        System.out.println( "Estimated Cost: " + totalCost); //And here
    }
}
```

The commented lines are what I would like to be formatted to 2 decimal places

Comment: Use `printf()` not `println()`.

Comment: Apart from @shmosel's comment, take the [tour] and please indent your code correctly

Comment: thank you! I haven't actually been taught how to properly indent yet but I'll work on it

Comment: @Nicole Then use an IDE. They help you indent code correctly, and can auto-format badly written code too.

Comment: For indentation I suggest using an environment that takes care of that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `printf` as `@shmosel` suggested, or use `String.format`:

```
System.out.println( "Service Total: " + String.format("%.2f", serviceTotal));
```

See [this page](https://www.dotnetperls.com/format-java) for more usage examples.